# Change language (or region) of PSN account

Tags: ps4, psn, ps5

I live in Bulgaria, and bought a PS5 recently. Of course, I've set the English language for my account, but since my native language is Russian I would like to play games with Russian voice acting. I understand that some games do not have Russian voice acting at all (for example, RDR2), but some of them absolutely definitely have Russian voice (God Of War, Horizon Zero Down, etc), but this is not shown for my account.

Can I change the region for my account (for example, by writing to Sony's technical support)? Will there be any problems and blocking of my console in the future?

I could create another account and set the Russian region, but the problem is that I have already bought more than 10 games on my current account and I would not want to abandon them.

Comment: System language and PSN region should be different things, aren't they?

Comment: Are you saying there is a special Russian voiced version of games that you can't get on the PSN store or you want games to default to Russian where possible? Because I think the later is developer dependent (and just matches your system settings).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to play games with Russian voice acting

Most games with Russian voice acting need to be purchased with a Russian Account, as they are language locked to prevent abuse of regional pricing.

You could change the system language to Russian, but if that doesn't works you would need to create a Russian account and buy the games again with a Russian payment method.